# Sesgar div con css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-transform

Buen día, he estado investigando un poco acerca de como realizar lo siguiente, pero lo que he encontrado a pesar de que es parecido a lo que quiero lograr no es exactamente lo que busco, lo que busco realizar es sesgar un div y que el resultado sea igual al de la imagen que muestro a continuación:

[image: Resultado esperado]

De antemano gracias.

Esto es lo que llevo realizado:

```css
.contenedor{
transform: skew(0deg,-2deg);
-ms-transform: skew(0deg,-2deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg,-2deg);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(33,33,33,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(33,33,33,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(33,33,33,1);

background-color: #111;
margin-top: 60px;
padding: 75px;
}
.contenido{
transform: skew(0deg,2deg);
-ms-transform: skew(0deg,2deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg,2deg);

background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor" style="">
<div class="contenido">
Contenido, esto no debe ir sesgado para que pueda ser legible
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código que llevas hasta el momento?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta ahí se encuentra lo que llevo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He editado un poco tu código para lograr la forma, me ayudé un poco con esta [herramienta](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/). Solo debes mover el padding del `.contenedor`

```css
.contenedor {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 17%, 100% 83%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 17%, 100% 83%, 0% 100%);
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 180px;
  padding: 100px 30px;
}
.contenido {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='contenedor'>
  <div class="contenido">
    Contenido, esto no debe ir sesgado para que pueda ser legible
  </div>
</div>
```